# Вечное подключение к SQL, через Node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-server, node-modules

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'sa',
  password : '1234',
  database: 'TodoList',
  port: 3306
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * FROM Todo',function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
});

connection.end();
```

К самому серверу я успешно подключался, через SQL server management, как через windows аутентификацию, так и через юзера sa.
Порт 3306 открыл в SQL server configuration manager
Вот лог ошибки после 2 минут ожидания

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\Лера\Documents\html\sqltest\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\Лера\Documents\html\sqltest\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\Лера\Documents\html\sqltest\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Лера\Documents\html\sqltest\app.js:10:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  fatal: true
}
```

Подскажите решение проблемы
UPDATE
Я переопределил зависимости и переписал код

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mssql": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "name": "sqltest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

```
const sql = require('mssql')
const sqlConfig = {
  user: 'sa',
  password: '1234',
  database: 'TodoList',
  server: 'localhost',
  port: 1433,
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
  },
  options: {
    encrypt: true, // for azure
    trustServerCertificate: false // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs
  }
}

async () => {
    try {
        // make sure that any items are correctly URL encoded in the connection string
        await sql.connect(sqlConfig)
        const result = await sql.query`select * from Todo`
        console.log('test')
        console.dir(result)
    } catch (err) {
        // ... error checks
    }
}
```

однако соединение, все равно не работает ничего не выводит, даже ошибки

```
PS C:\Users\Лера\Documents\html\sqltest> npm run start

> sqltest@1.0.0 start
> node app.js

PS C:\Users\Лера\Documents\html\sqltest>
```

Вот открытый порт
[image: открытый порт]

Comment: ```Порт 3306 открыл в SQL server configuration manager``` чуточку точнее в этом месте, какой порт какой схемы адресации вы открыли? localhost это один(или сразу оба) из вариантов адресов ```127.0.0.1``` и второй ```[::1]```, вы порт открыли на оба адреса? на один? В фаерволе порт тоже открыт?

Comment: Тьфу, сижу и не пойму что же не cходится в вашем вопрос.....
У вас в итоге какой сервер? MySQL ? MSSQL ? а то вы пытаетесь соединится с MySQL а софт называете от MSSQL

Comment: Я открыл tcp для всех подключений статический порт 3306

Comment: Я не особо разбираюсь в базах данных и не знаю, что они отличаются, но я же не писал про mssql

Comment: Вы не писали про MSSQL явно, но тем не менее в тегах вашего вопроса стоит SQL-server(что есть MSSQL), и название ПО которые вы приводите в рамках MySQL - мне не известны, зато известны одноименные утилиты для администрирования MSSQL сервера, поэтому и уточняю, у вас точно MySQL установлен? а то похоже что MSSQL, так же я не очень в курсе чтоб у MySQL было популярно использовать sa, в My всегда был root по умолчанию, а в MS какраз sa (но это могли и поменять) вобщем либо очень много совпадений либо у вас MSSQL и порт немного неверный :)

Comment: Теперь понял о чем вы, у меня установлен mssql, то есть нужно использовать mssql npm пакет?

Comment: Да, эти БД не совместимы на уровне драйверов :) либо устанавливать MySQL либо использовать другой пакет(для mssql)

Comment: вы не прописали вызов функции (async () => {})()

Comment: Даааа, жизнь боль, когда ты слепой